# Texture Paint, merged objects can not be painted properly

Tags: texture-painting

I merged some pipes and but the texture painting behaves super unpredictable. I can paint all the pipes but not when I am close e.g. The biggest issue is that sometimes I can paint more than one pipe and sometimes on pipe is totally ignored which leads to ugly border (see picture).

I would be so happy about some help! Cheers!

[image]

Comment: first make sure that the normals are correctly flipped and that your UV islands don't overlap

Comment: Both looks fine to me... If you might have a look in the file I would highly appreciate it. https://pasteall.org/blend/28d316bb6b2f45caa829e89d97c9c741

Comment: yes that's weird, I've reinitialized the brush and re-unwrapped but it is still not good, if I append into another file it works fine though, so it has to do with a setting...

Comment: Okay, thank you for that, I just started with texture painting!

Comment: maybe someone will find why it's buggy